# css embed no scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar, embed, hidden

Alright, I have a a page with an ajax button on it. When you hit the ajax button, it throws an embed object into the 'data' div. Everything works fine, my problem is that the embed is creating a scrollbar that I don't want. Any ideas on how to prevent the scrollbar? I've already tried throwing 'overflow: hidden' everywhere I could with no success =/

~html~

http://pastebin.com/WZ2YzDVb

~my.css~

http://pastebin.com/iR335BNj

~ajax embed data~

```
<embed width=100% height=100% type='text/html' style='overflow: hidden' src='source'>
```

I used pastebin to keep my post clean.

Comment: For a quick check, set the embed to 50% width/height. Do the scrollbars go away? If so, it means the scrollbars were on the parent. Otherwise you should be able to see that the scrollbars are in the embed themselves. If this is the case, can you let us know what's being embedded?

Comment: I'm embedding another webpage. The scrollbar is there no matter what size the embed is.

Comment: Is there are reason you're not using an iFrame?

Answer (score 4):

When you see the scroll bar in an  element, you are actually seeing the scroll bar for that element's webpage. You can't fix it my giving the `<embed>` a style, you have to give the `<body>` of the `<embed>` a style. Here's what solved it for me:

[MainFile.html]

```
<html>
   <body>
      <embed style='border:1px solid black;' src='EmebdedFile.html'></embed>
   </body>
</html>
```

[EmbededFile.html]

```
<html>
   <body style='overflow:hidden'>
      <img src='smile.png' style='height:1000px; width:1000px;'></img>
   </body>
</html>
```

Notice that 'overflow:hidden' is in the HTML file of the embedded element.

Answer (score 1):

Use your embed tag inside a container with overflow hidden. Then set the width of the embed with 100% + 17px (the default width of a scrollbar).

Answer (score -1):

Just add this code to your css file :

```
img, video, object, embed {
max-width: 100%;    
height: auto;
overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried  it, doesn't change anything =/

Comment: your embed code is wrong, try this please :

<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="text/html" style="overflow: hidden" src="source">

Comment: why not use iframe for text/html embedded ?

Answer (score -1):

make height='auto' width='auto'