# Embeded page and issue with css when no scrollbar

Tags: css, iframe, scrollbar, embed

Any ideas how to avoid vertical scrollbar when have embeded page and not destroy the body background on embeded page? Maybe anyone know how to achieve this with proper css?

http://inspiracje.domino.pl/streetball/

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Applied to the embed either through a style attribute on the HTML or using separate CSS.

This seems to be similar the issue you are having... [css embed no scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607157/css-embed-no-scrollbar)

Comment: Done, but this is not the solution. It does not give any effect.

Comment: Interesting. Would you mind including some code in your example so I can help more effectively?